# Using Font-awesome pro in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm new with font-awesome in rails, and I try to find an easy way to install font-awesome pro in rails? I have search the web, but there is so many unclear solution. Could someone can give me an easy way to achieve this installation?

I have a pro account,

I do not want to use CDN,

I'm using rails 5.1.4 and ruby 2.5.0p0

Thanks

Comment: Fontawesome pro documentation is behind a paywall

Comment: @Tachyons do you have a link, I found nothing in documentation about rails

Answer (score 1):

The documentation about "Rails" is really in Sass, but that's only because Rails uses Sass by default. Not to mention, the [original documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass) is actually specific to Sass and thus isn't perfectly tailored to Rails.

Using Sass, hosting Font Awesome yourself and allowing Sass inheritance:

- Downloading Font Awesome. Google `Hosting Font Awesome Yourself` and click the first result. Download and unarchive the zip file.
- Putting Font Awesome in your Rails project.

  - Create the folders `/vendor/assets/fonts` and `/vendor/assets/stylesheets` if they do not exist.
  - From your Font Awesome unarchived download:

    - place `scss` into `/vendor/assets/stylesheets` and rename it `fontawesome`.
    - place `webfonts` into `/vendor/assets/fonts` and rename it `fontawesome`.
- Importing the font to your Sass. In your `application.scss` (with chosen [styles](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started)), preferably at or near the top:

  ```
  $fa-font-path: 'fontawesome';
  @import "fontawesome/fontawesome";
  @import "fontawesome/<style>"; // for each style you use
  ```
- Edit styles to properly import assets. Inside each style's scss (i.e. brands.scss), there are `url` links. Change each `url` to `asset-url` to properly use the rails asset pipeline.
- Precompile the font. This can be configured a multitude of ways, but I put in `assets.rb`:

  ```
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << File.join('fontawesome', /\.(?:svg|eot|woff2?|ttf)\z/.to_s)
  ```

---

Example with Inheritance for a solid home button with the class `nav-home`:

```
# /app/assets/stylesheets/application.rb
$fa-font-path: 'fontawesome';
@import "fontawesome/fontawesome";
@import "fontawesome/solid";

.nav-home {
  @extend %fa-icon;
  @extend .fas;

  &:before {
    content: fa-content($fa-var-home);
  }
}

# /app/views/<view>/<view_action>.html.erb
<%= link_to('', root_path, class: 'nav-home') %>
```

This makes an icon-only home button.

Alternatively, you could use html [links or scripts](https://fontawesome.com/start), but I think you'd miss out on using Sass inheritance and really cleaning up your `html.erb`.